# How to generate links towards right side in force layout D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How to generate  links arc angles towards right side in force layout D3.js, as shown in the image:

[image: desired output]

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
path.attr("d", function(d) {

    var x1 = d.source.x,
        y1 = d.source.y,
        x2 = d.target.x,
        y2 = d.target.y,
        dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = y2 - y1,

    if (x1 === x2) {

        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dy + dy * dy);
        return "M" +
            d.source.x + "," +
            d.source.y + "A" +
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
            d.target.x + "," +
            d.target.y;

    }
});
```

But seems some on left and some on right. Please help me out of this.

Comment: if (x1 === x2) {
       var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dy + dy * dy); // note that this is always equal to Math.abs(dy)
       var sweep = 1;
       if (y1 > y2) {
        sweep = 0
       }
       return "M" +
        d.source.x + ","+ d.source.y +
        "A" + dr + "," + dr +
        " 0 0," + sweep + " " +
        d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always setting `sweep-flag` to 1, so it will draw clockwise from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). This will be on the right when going down, and on the left when going up. You can normalize this by checking whether the orientation is up or down, and then either swapping the order of points or reversing the sweep direction:

```
if (x1 === x2) {
    var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dy + dy * dy); // note that this is always equal to Math.abs(dy)
    var sweep = 0;
    if (y1 > y2) {
        sweep = 1
    }
    return "M" +
        d.source.x + "," d.source.y +
        "A" + dr + "," + dr +
        " 0 0," + sweep + " " +
        d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Phssthpok. Its working but my condition is like when (x1 === x2  ) are in same direction then i have to make the link to bend. :(

Comment: Keep the (x1 === x2) comparison. Add an additional comparison for the y values afterwards.

Comment: :( its not working out. some links bending towards right and some on left.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the correct way to specify drawing the arc the other direction is with `sweep-flag`, not with `x-axis rotation`.

Comment: Is it possible to add some distance between each link as  above image ?

Comment: You could vary the `rx` parameter to get some distance. It's hard to say how much you would want to vary it by, maybe multiply by a fraction of the available width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73636/discussion-between-fekkydev-and-phssthpok).

Comment: Instead of `Math.sqrt(dx * dy + dy * dy)` shouldn't it be `Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)` ?